# Generating java from wsdl and xsd error

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am a beginner in wsdl/xsd trying to generate Java classes with the following two
files

I am getting a number of errors from wsdl2java including the wsdl file defines no services, and that elements from the xsd file cannot be found.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

**ChipDataJob.xsd**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://contmgmt.ecm.omega/WorkspaceManager/ChipDataJob"
    targetNamespace="http://contmgmt.ecm.omega/WorkspaceManager/ChipDataJob"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="dataChipperJob" type="tns:ChipJob"></xs:element>
    <xs:element name="dataChipperResponse" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
    <xs:element name="cancelResponse" type="xs:boolean"></xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="ChipJob">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="outputFilename" type="xs:string">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="uuidDataObjects">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:list itemType="xs:string" />
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="parameters" type="tns:ChipParameters"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ChipParameters">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="chipStartTime" type="xs:double">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="chipEndTime" type="xs:double">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="fillDuration" type="xs:float">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="GapFillMethod">
                <xs:simpleType final="restriction">
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="NONE" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="ZERO_FILL" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="StitchMarkerFormat">
                <xs:simpleType final="restriction">
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="NONE" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="FILL" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="SequenceMethod">
                <xs:simpleType final="restriction">
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="TIMECODE" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="MANUAL" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
```

**DataChipper.wsdl**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://contmgmt.ecm.omega/WorkspaceManager/ChipDataJob"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    targetNamespace="http://contmgmt.ecm.omega/WorkspaceManager/ChipDataJob">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema
            targetNamespace="http://contmgmt.ecm.omega/WorkspaceManager/ChipDataJob"
            xmlns:tns="http://contmgmt.ecm.omega/WorkspaceManager/ChipDataJob"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="qualified">
            <xsd:include schemaLocation="ChipDataJob.xsd" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <!-- Chip Message -->
    <wsdl:message name="dataChipperJob">
        <wsdl:part name="job" element="tns:ChipJob" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="dataChipperResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="taskId" element="xs:long" />
    </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:message name="cancelResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="cancelSuccess" element="xs:boolean" />
    </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="DataChipperServicePort">
    <wsdl:operation name="submitRequest">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:dataChipperJob"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:dataChipperResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="cancelRequest">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:dataChipperResponse"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:cancelResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: What library or tool are you trying to use?

Comment: I am using wsdl2java

Comment: You can start with posting the exact error messages/stack traces that you're receiving

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your XSD or WSDL.

Comment: Removed web tag as too high level.  Added wsdl2java tag as it is the tool being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found to be wrong with the wsdl.

```
<wsdl:message name="dataChipperJob">
    <wsdl:part name="job" element="tns:ChipJob" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="dataChipperResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="taskId" element="xs:long" />
</wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="cancelResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="cancelSuccess" element="xs:boolean" />
</wsdl:message>
```

The element tags are refering to the element Types not the elements themselves
These should be changed to

```
<wsdl:message name="dataChipperJob">
    <wsdl:part name="job" element="tns:dataChipperJob" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="dataChipperResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="taskId" element="tns:dataChipperResponse" />
</wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="cancelResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="cancelSuccess" element="tns:cancelResponse" />
</wsdl:message>
```

Also the wsdl should define a binding and a service.

Comment: Cool, good to hear you managed to solve your problem. Please accept your own answer by clicking the check mark at the left, below the answer score!